# Converting Shell Script to Dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, shell, dockerfile, sh

I have Java app and want to generate docker image, I have shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

java -version

export APPLICATION_DIR=$PWD

for rJarFile in `ls ${APPLICATION_DIR}/lib/*.jar`
do
        export CLASSPATH=$rJarFile:$CLASSPATH
done

export CLASSPATH=$APPLICATION_DIR/classes:$CLASSPATH

java -Xverify:none -Xmx2048m -Djava.awt.headless=true -DFI_IS_CONFIGSER=N -DFICLIENT_APP_PATH=${APPLICATION_DIR} -DFI_APP_NAME=FIONLINE -DFI_BASE_INSTANCE_ID=1 -DPRODUCT_BOOTSTRAP_FILE=${APPLICATION_DIR}/data/BootstrapFile.properties -DFEBA_SYS_PATH=${APPLICATION_DIR}/data
```

And I try to convert it into Dockerfile like this

```
# FROM openjdk:8
FROM openjdk:11

RUN javac -version

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

ENV APPLICATION_DIR=/usr/src/app

RUN echo $APPLICATION_DIR

RUN for rJarFile in `ls ${APPLICATION_DIR}/lib/*.jar`; do export CLASSPATH=$rJarFile:$CLASSPATH; done

RUN echo $CLASSPATH

ENV $CLASSPATH=$APPLICATION_DIR/classes:$CLASSPATH

# Run app
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Xverify:none", "-Xmx2048m", "-Djava.awt.headless=true", "-DFI_IS_CONFIGSER=N", "-DFICLIENT_APP_PATH=${APPLICATION_DIR} -DFI_APP_NAME=FIONLINE -DFI_BASE_INSTANCE_ID=1", "-DPRODUCT_BOOTSTRAP_FILE=${APPLICATION_DIR}/data/BootstrapFile.properties", "-DFEBA_SYS_PATH=${APPLICATION_DIR}/data"]
```

It can be generated, but there's an error when I try to run it like this:

```
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:459: container init caused: setenv: invalid argument: unknown
```

I've also changed this script `` RUN for rJarFile in `ls ${APPLICATION_DIR}/lib/*.jar`; do export ``  into this `RUN for rJarFile in ls ${APPLICATION_DIR}/lib/*.jar; do export CLASSPATH=$rJarFile:$CLASSPATH; done`, but none of them working. I don't want to make Dockerfile execute the script. Below is logs when i generate and run it.

[image: generating]

Comment: I don't see how this is related to bash. Your shell script seems to be a simple `sh` script.

Comment: Your exec form is not correct => `ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Xverify:none", "-Xmx2048m", "-Djava.awt.headless=true", "-DFI_IS_CONFIGSER=N", "-DFICLIENT_APP_PATH=${APPLICATION_DIR}", "-DFI_APP_NAME=FIONLINE", "-DFI_BASE_INSTANCE_ID=1", "-DPRODUCT_BOOTSTRAP_FILE=${APPLICATION_DIR}/data/BootstrapFile.properties", "-DFEBA_SYS_PATH=${APPLICATION_DIR}/data"]`

Comment: @Zeitounator the shell script is running well when executed, which part is not correct?

Comment: Compare your entrypoint definition with the one I pasted above and your have the answer. Every command line element must be in its own list element.

Comment: now i got ```Error: Could not find or load main class com.infosys.feba.framework.batch.scheduler.SchedulerInitializer
```

Comment: Please consider the suggestion I posted in my answer - move the script back into a separate file. If it has been working previously - it should still be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update the classpath as you do with:

```
ENV $CLASSPATH=$APPLICATION_DIR/classes:$CLASSPATH
```

instead you can do

```
ENV CLASSPATH=$APPLICATION_DIR/classes:$CLASSPATH
```

Also - please consider moving the script into a separate shell script and adding into the container. This would greatly simplify the Dockerfile, for example:

```
# FROM openjdk:8
FROM openjdk:11

RUN javac -version

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

ENV APPLICATION_DIR=/usr/src/app

RUN echo $APPLICATION_DIR

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/start_java.sh"]
```

and keep your existing script inside `start_java.sh`

Comment: I'm trying the first solution, but still got error when running. Is the loop correct?

Comment: Just move the script back into a separate file. Keeping it inside the Dockerfile makes it unreadable and creates errors.

Comment: Yes, I already tried it, and it's working. But, I'm still curious about convert it to dockerfile script. Is it really impossible?